# How to publish Jenkins job icons externally?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using [Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) to assign certain icons to Jenkins jobs on certain conditions and I'd like to publish these promotion icons.

How can I generate external links to these icons per each job, so they're accessible externally?

—————

For example I'd like to create the table in `README.md` on GitHub like:

```
Job 1 | ![](link_to_icon_of_job_1)
Job 2 | ![](link_to_icon_of_job_2)
Job 3 | ![](link_to_icon_of_job_3)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "[Embeddable Build Status Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Embeddable+Build+Status+Plugin)" will do exactly that.

Note: This requires your Jenkins server to be accessible from the internet if you're using GitHub because they cache all images in their CDN.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to do something similar (embed build status icons into email notifications) but since our build system is not publicly accessible, I ended up posting the status icons to imgur and referencing those images by storing the URL in variables according to state.

Here are some snippets from my email template Groovyscript:

**Defining the URLs:**

```
def images = [:]
images["SUCCESS"] = "http://i.imgur.com/uXlqCxW.gif"
images["PASSED"] = "http://i.imgur.com/uXlqCxW.gif"
images["UNSTABLE"] = "http://i.imgur.com/QkQbxR3.gif"
images["SKIPPED"] = "http://i.imgur.com/QkQbxR3.gif"
images["FAILURE"] = "http://i.imgur.com/LUveOg7.gif"
images["FAILED"] = "http://i.imgur.com/LUveOg7.gif"
images["ABORTED"] = "http://i.imgur.com/jSdrWWP.gif"
images["NOT_RUN"] = "http://i.imgur.com/jSdrWWP.gif"
```

**Using the URLs in the email:**

```
<img src="${images[build.result.toString()]}" />
```